# Why does my Xamarin.Forms app crash after inserting data to a SQLite database from a web API?

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app calls data from a web API in XML form, deserializes it with Newtonsoft.JsonConvert, and now I'm trying to get it to insert that data into a local SQLite database within the app - this is triggered by pressing a button.

The data for this particular table has two columns and seven rows, and this is stored as the class Location.cs.

Here's my code:

```
public MainPage()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 } 

 public async void GetLocations()
 {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("my API url is here");
    var locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(response);
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
    conn.CreateTable<Location>();
    conn.Insert(locations);
    conn.Close();
 }


 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 GetLocations();

    //await Navigation.PushAsync(new LocationPage());
    //this code navigates to the next page in the app
 }
```

So I've put breakpoints on the last three lines within the GetLocations method, and the first two go off perfectly; QuickWatch tells me all the data has been inserted successfully into the correct format.

It's after that, presumably when I try to close the table connection that the app crashes and I get "System.ArgumentException: 'method arguments are incompatible'".

It does not hit the `conn.Close();` breakpoint at all, it seems to finish the insert and then throw the exception. I don't know why this is happening -  I doubt it is related to memory, as the Android emulator I test on has 4GB of RAM assigned and this table has only seven rows.

EDIT: Included sample of data from API in XML form vs. class as defined in C#.

```
<Location>
<Location_Desc>B1_SAMPLE LOCATION</Location_Desc>
<LocationCode>B1</LocationCode>
</Location>
```

And

```
public class Location
    {

        public string Location_Desc { get; set; }
        public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT 2: Included output from debugger.

```
09-09 14:37:40.676 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-09 14:37:40.677 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
09-09 14:37:40.677 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
09-09 14:37:40.677 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_float_method_a'.
09-09 14:37:40.758 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 3 of APPNAME.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLite-net, Version=1.5.231.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
09-09 14:37:40.758 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref APPNAME[0xf01626a0] -> SQLite-net[0xf01627c0]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.760 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of System.Net.Http.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:40.760 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xebce8ae0] -> System[0xf016d200]: 6
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 5 of APPNAME.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref APPNAME[0xf01626a0] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xf01625e0]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 2 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Collections[0xd0c204c0] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Collections.dll[0xd2bf1200]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Collections' (System.Collections.dll)
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Collections[0xd0c204c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Collections.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Collections.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Collections.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Collections/System.Collections.config'.
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Collections[0xd0c204c0]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Collections.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0xd0c204c0] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 62
09-09 14:37:40.761 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 3 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0xd229ec80] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Runtime.Extensions.dll[0xd2bf1700]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions' (System.Runtime.Extensions.dll)
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Runtime.Extensions[0xd229ec80] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Extensions/System.Runtime.Extensions.config'.Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll [External]

09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Runtime.Extensions[0xd229ec80]: 2
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of System.Runtime.Extensions.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0xd229ec80] -> System[0xf016d200]: 7
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Runtime.Extensions.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0xd229ec80] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 63
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.11.121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535
09-09 14:37:40.762 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xf01628e0]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:40.796 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of Mono.Android.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:40.796 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xf016d0e0] -> System.Net.Http[0xebce8ae0]: 3
Thread started:  #2
09-09 14:37:41.083 D/NetworkSecurityConfig(19158): Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
09-09 14:37:41.210 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport attempting to load: 'libmono-native.so'.
09-09 14:37:41.216 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport loaded library './libmono-native.so'.
09-09 14:37:41.216 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'libmono-native.so' ('./libmono-native.so').
09-09 14:37:41.216 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
09-09 14:37:41.216 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
09-09 14:37:41.216 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
09-09 14:37:41.262 I/Choreographer(19158): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
09-09 14:37:41.884 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-09 14:37:41.885 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
09-09 14:37:41.885 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
09-09 14:37:41.885 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method'.
09-09 14:37:41.992 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-09 14:37:41.992 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
09-09 14:37:41.992 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
09-09 14:37:41.992 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
09-09 14:37:41.995 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-09 14:37:41.995 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:41.995 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:41.995 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:41.999 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-09 14:37:41.999 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:41.999 D/Mono    (19158): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:41.999 D/Mono    (19158): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'.
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 9 of netstandard.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Numerics, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Numerics[0xd0c1fec0] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Numerics.dll[0xcfbfd800]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Numerics' (System.Numerics.dll)
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Numerics[0xd0c1fec0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Numerics.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.173 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Numerics.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.174 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Numerics.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.174 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Numerics/System.Numerics.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.174 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xf016e6a0] -> System.Numerics[0xd0c1fec0]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.174 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Numerics.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.174 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Numerics[0xd0c1fec0] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 64
Loaded assembly: System.Numerics.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 10 of netstandard.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xcf7bcd80] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xcfbfdd00]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xcf7bcd80] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xf016e6a0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xcf7bcd80]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Runtime.Serialization.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.252 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xcf7bcd80] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 65
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:42.277 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 3 of netstandard.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Data, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Data[0xcf7bce40] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Data.dll[0xcfbfbf00]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Data' (System.Data.dll)
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Data[0xcf7bce40] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Data.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Data.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Data.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Data/System.Data.config'.
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xf016e6a0] -> System.Data[0xcf7bce40]: 2
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Data.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0xcf7bce40] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 66
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 2 of System.Data.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.278 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0xcf7bce40] -> System.Xml[0xebce8a80]: 4
Loaded assembly: System.Data.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:42.289 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of System.Data.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.289 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0xcf7bce40] -> System[0xf016d200]: 8
09-09 14:37:42.290 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 4 of System.Data.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:42.290 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0xcf7bce40] -> System.Core[0xf016d7a0]: 6
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
09-09 14:37:43.017 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 9 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, Version=1.1.11.121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8226ea5df37bcae9
09-09 14:37:43.017 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xf0162880]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.019 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, Version=1.1.11.121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c301db686d0bd12
09-09 14:37:43.019 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xf0162880] -> SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3[0xf01629a0]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.019 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.11.121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535
09-09 14:37:43.019 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3[0xf01629a0] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xf01628e0]: 3
09-09 14:37:43.019 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 2 of SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.1.11.121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535
09-09 14:37:43.020 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xf0162880] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xf01628e0]: 4
09-09 14:37:43.024 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport attempting to load: 'e_sqlite3'.
09-09 14:37:43.024 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport error loading library './e_sqlite3': '(null)'.
09-09 14:37:43.025 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport loaded library './libe_sqlite3.so'.
09-09 14:37:43.025 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.025 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_libversion_number'.
09-09 14:37:43.037 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.037 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_open_v2'.
09-09 14:37:43.057 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.057 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_busy_timeout'.
09-09 14:37:43.069 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.069 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'.
09-09 14:37:43.084 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.084 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_step'.
09-09 14:37:43.087 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.087 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_type'.
09-09 14:37:43.088 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 5 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:43.088 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Reflection[0xcf7be520] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Reflection.dll[0xcfbff600]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.088 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Reflection' (System.Reflection.dll)
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Reflection[0xcf7be520] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Reflection.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Reflection.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection/System.Reflection.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Reflection[0xcf7be520]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Reflection.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection[0xcf7be520] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 67
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 12 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Globalization[0xcf7be400] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Globalization.dll[0xcfbffb00]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Globalization' (System.Globalization.dll)
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Globalization[0xcf7be400] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Globalization.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.089 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Globalization.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Globalization.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Globalization/System.Globalization.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Globalization[0xcf7be400]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Globalization.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Globalization[0xcf7be400] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 68
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 2 of System.Runtime.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.090 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime[0xebce88a0] -> System[0xf016d200]: 9
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Globalization.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:43.112 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.112 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_text'.
09-09 14:37:43.116 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.116 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_finalize'.
09-09 14:37:43.121 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 8 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Linq[0xcf7be460] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Linq.dll[0xce8d1000]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Linq' (System.Linq.dll)
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Linq[0xcf7be460] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Linq.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Linq.dll.so' not found: (null)
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.dll [External]09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.dll.config'.

09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq/System.Linq.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Linq[0xcf7be460]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of System.Linq.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.122 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Linq[0xcf7be460] -> System.Core[0xf016d7a0]: 7
09-09 14:37:43.133 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 10 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:43.133 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Threading[0xcf7be580] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Threading.dll[0xce8d1500]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.133 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Threading' (System.Threading.dll)
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Threading[0xcf7be580] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Threading.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Threading.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Threading.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Threading/System.Threading.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Threading[0xcf7be580]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Threading.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.134 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Threading[0xcf7be580] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 69
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:43.145 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 1 of System.Collections.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.145 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0xd0c204c0] -> System.Core[0xf016d7a0]: 8
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 11 of SQLite-net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Reflection.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Image addref System.Reflection.Extensions[0xcf7be4c0] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Reflection.Extensions.dll[0xce8d1a00]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Reflection.Extensions' (System.Reflection.Extensions.dll)
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly System.Reflection.Extensions[0xcf7be4c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image 'System.Reflection.Extensions.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll.so' not found: (null)
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.Extensions.dll.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection.Extensions/System.Reflection.Extensions.config'.
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xf01627c0] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0xcf7be4c0]: 2
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Loading reference 0 of System.Reflection.Extensions.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
09-09 14:37:43.148 D/Mono    (19158): Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection.Extensions[0xcf7be4c0] -> mscorlib[0xf0162580]: 70
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
09-09 14:37:43.246 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.247 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_count'.
09-09 14:37:43.249 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.249 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_name'.
09-09 14:37:43.262 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.262 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_int'.
09-09 14:37:43.714 D/Mono    (19158): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('./libe_sqlite3.so').
09-09 14:37:43.715 D/Mono    (19158): Searching for 'sqlite3_close_v2'.
**System.ArgumentException:** 'method arguments are incompatible'
```

Comment: It is failing on the Insert.  When you get to a break point it is before the instruction is executed.  Which means the response and the location class are not compatible.  Probably the number of items in the json and the class are not the same or one of the properties in the response cannot be cast to the type in the class.

Comment: @Nick XML? You deserialize JSON in your code example. And that is a single object, not a list/collection

Comment: @Nkosi That's what the API url returns in my browser. Yes it is one object, there are six more that form the total list and they are all in that format.

Comment: You need to debug your code to make sure you are getting the correct data in the correct format. What does quick watch say is the value of `locations` when you step through your code.

Comment: It says locations has a count of 7, and displays locations[0] through locations[6], i.e. every row of data from the API. Expanding each of these shows Location_Desc and LocationCode as strings.

Comment: See comments in answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes most likely because you have an unhandled exception in an `async void` fire and forget function. There may be an issue with the insert, but because of the async void you are unable to catch the thrown exception.

avoid `async void` except for actual **event handlers**.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Refactor

Location

```
[Table]
public class Location {
    public string Location_Desc { get; set; }
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage

```
public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
} 

static Lazy<HttpClient> httpClient = new Lazy<HttpClient>();

public async Task GetLocations() {        
    var response = await httpClient.Value.GetStringAsync("my API url is here");
    var locations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(response);
    using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation)) {
        conn.CreateTable<Location>();
        foreach(var location in locations) {
            conn.Insert(location);
        }
        //OR
        //conn.InsertAll(locations);
        conn.Close();
    }
}

//async-void allowed here because this is an event handler.
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await GetLocations();

    //await Navigation.PushAsync(new LocationPage());
    //this code navigates to the next page in the app
}
```

And `GetLocations` can wrap its content in a `try-catch` to handle any thrown exceptions.

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi, using `conn.InsertAll(locations);` is working properly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a collection when a single `Location` is expected for `Insert`.
Use `conn.InsertAll(locations)` instead